# Multithread file copy to different hard drive using c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, file, copy

I need to develop an application that can copy faster than OS copy using 1 thread to read source files and another thread to write them. Source and target files are located in different hard drive.

My question is how to pass the result of source read thread into target write thread without resulting some race condition and still maintain top performance of the copy process to achieve faster copy process than OS copy.

Comment: Show us the code you've tried already.

Comment: If the targets reside on the same hard drive, it's unlikely that adding more threads will do much for performance improvements IMHO.

Comment: The writers of the OS have likely spent a lot of time making their copying routines as efficient as possible, and they have the advantage of intimate knowledge of how their OS works.  So I wouldn't hold my breath about getting faster results than they get.

Answer (score 0):

Use a bounded queue.
You can use any queue ([TBB](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/containers_overview/concurrent_bounded_queue_cls.htm), std::deque, [cirtular buffer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/circular_buffer.html), whatever). If it isn't thread-safe and/or blocking then synchronize around it and use [conditional variables](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) for notification. You don't need smart tricks in the queue because passing a pointer to a chunk of data into the queue is much faster then the I/O, but if you really want to over-optimize then check the [disruptor](https://github.com/fsaintjacques/disruptor--) (described [here](http://lmax-exchange.github.io/disruptor/)).

To reviewers: Note that the question is about copying between different hard-drives, so a multithreaded copy *will* benefit it.

Comment: If your OS has async io, I dont see how multiple threads can speed things up. Of course this involves multiple threads, but behind the scenes

Comment: @W.B. I've dabbled with Linux AIO and with its limitations, user-space implementation and a complex API the threads are preferable. FreeBSD AIO is better but still limited and too complex. Today the threads are the preferred solution to the I/O problem on these systems, AFAIK. The threads will "just work", everywhere.

Comment: @W.B. If you want event-driven asynchronous I/O then it's better advice to go with `libuv` than with the system's AIO. But event-driven systems are inherently more complex (I use coroutines to simplify them, so it's one complex thing used to simplify another =).